# Cognitive Science podcasts to follow

Tags: learning

I'm currently trying to find interesting Cognitive Science related [podcasts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podcast) to follow. Only one I've found is [You are not so smart](https://soundcloud.com/youarenotsosmart). Does anyone know anything else? Preferably in English.

If the question is off-topic, not constructive or opinion based, please let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: More recommendations [here](https://youtu.be/w5eBk9lR7dA) and in the comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are the ones I know about; there's much more about neuroscience than, say, theoretical or computational cognitive science, but a lot of the neuroscience podcasts cover cognitive science indirectly or partially.

[All in the Mind](http://www.abc.net.au/radionational/programs/allinthemind/)--it's also neuroscience and mental health stuff (a lot of mental health stuff)

[Brain Science Podcast](http://brainsciencepodcast.com/)--books about and interviews with researchers in neuroscience

[Neuropod](http://www.nature.com/neurosci/neuropod/index.html)--Nature's neuroscience podcast

[Neuroscene](http://neuroscene.com/)--"the future of neuroscience", mostly interviews or topical explorations

[Naked Neuroscience](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/podcasts/neuroscience/nocache/1/)--the neuroscience offshoot of Cambridge University's Naked Scientists

Answer (score 8):

I actually think this is a bit tougher than it sounds because of how broad cogsci is as a field. Not too long ago, I asked a similar question on twitter; to this end, here are the podcasts that I now regularly follow:

[99% Invisible](http://99percentinvisible.org/) - A show about design, and the factors influencing it.

[Lexicon Valley](http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley.html) - Covers language from "pet peeves, syntax and etymology to neurolinguistics and the death of languages".

[Brain Science Podcast](http://brainsciencepodcast.com/) - Mentioned in another answer. The host's in medicine, but the show discusses neuroscience and ow our brain makes us who we are.

[Very Bad Wizards](http://verybadwizards.com/) - One of my favourites. The product of a psychologist and a philosopher, sharing a marked inability to distinguish sacred from profane.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what's mentioned above I quite like "[Hidden Brain](http://www.npr.org/podcasts/510308/hidden-brain)" and I'm starting [one myself](http://datadistiller.ca/remix-to-cognition-podcast/). It's early days and very high level, introductory stuff, and I'd like to get into the more philosophical side of CogSci soon.

Answer (score 4):

I enjoy [Brain Matters](http://brainpodcast.com/), it's very neuroscience based & full of interesting people

Answer (score 4):

Many Minds (https://disi.org/manyminds/)! Always fascinating stuff from an angle you most likely haven't come across before.